# Spring configuration issues not easy to find solution for

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I have found several really awkward problems which took me 3hr+ to resolve. I was wondering if anyone could explain me why this is the case. I believe both of them belong to the very much same context so I have two questions. I hope reader will have patience as for me this is both intimidating and interesting behavior of sf.

I only know the error and resolution, but not satisfied until I understand:

1. **Guidance I follow:** Have one configuration file - use package scan inside of your root **customConfig** only(declared via mapping in web.xml), make sure **servlet-context.xml** only scans controllers' package. All other context files import via import directive at the very beginning of your **customConfig**.

1.1 **Error if you do it other way:** Dependency injection(of various components) will dramatically fail with multiple overlapping config package scanning.

1.2 **Error if you do it other way:** Transaction during service request of transactionManager in context with **entityManagerFactory** will fail if **servlet-context.xml** scans the same package. (i.e. same service package as your **customConfig** scans)

2: **LocaleChangeInterceptor** can only be declared in **servlet-context** - won't work in custom root configuration, reason unknown(doesn't work even if adding package scan for controllers package inside **customConfig** however now funny bit - **SessionLocaleResolver** on the other hand will work ok if defined in custom config! )

Q1: So it is me to blame who as human was mistakenly adding overlapping context-component package scan or it would be logical for Spring to resolve these collisions? Or they should be resolved but it doesn't work for me for some reason?

I observed fellow developer and smiled when he told it is best not to touch spring configuration nor try to improve it nor try to update it. I smiled, now I clearly don't(I now find myself intimated by this sf config violence), after all of this do you think it is ok to place everything inside just a single configuration file like **servlet-context.xml** ?

Q2: What is the magic behind **LocaleChangeInterceptor**, I've spent around 5 hours fixing it until just moved in "try-and-fail" mood it into **servlet-context** and it worked.

Second is a pure mystery to solve. Nothing fancy inside **customConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- 
<import resource="securityContext.xml"/>  -->
<import resource="jpaContext.xml"/> 


<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.app" />


<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>


<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="en_GB" />
</bean>

     <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
    </mvc:interceptors> ...
```

After firing ?lang=locale_LOCALE request nothing will happen - no error, no indication , app will load successfully and page will just be reloaded under the same locale.

However placing this interceptor code inside **servlet-context.xml** below will resolve on locale request successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.app.controller" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


<interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
    </interceptors>


</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LocalChangeInterceptor` and `LocaleResolver` must be defined in the `servlet-context.xml`. `<context:annotation-driven />` is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />`

In your root context you are also scanning for `@Controller` you need to exclude them.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.app">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:compoment-scan>
```

Basically all the web related things (and the things which are used by the `DispatcherServlet`) must be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Due to its nature it will only look into its own local application context for the beans it needs instead of in its parents.

The reason for this is that you can have multiple DispatcherServlets each with its own configuration, this would break if it would load the configuration from the root application context.